# Can you specify two formats in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I need that a field on my JSON scheme to be either date or datetime. It can have any of those formats. Using the `format` property, is it possible to use both formats?

Comment: I myself asked the same question. However is it even good to use such a pattern? Wouldn't it make more sense to always transmit a `datetime` and an `allday` boolean flag instead? I am not sure, its 50:50, maybe you can give me a better opinion on that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In OpenAPI 3.x, you can use [`anyOf`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/):

```yaml
type: string
anyOf:
  - format: date
  - format: date-time
```

OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`) does not support `anyOf`, but as a workaround you can provide a custom regex `pattern` instead of the `format`.